# Krusader window too wide - can't be changed

Tags: window, krusader

Krusader seems like a great program (very similar to Total Commander in Windows). But it opens up a window which is wider/broader than the screen, and it seems impossible to shrink it. That is VERY unpractical.
But I CAN change the height of the window. Neither is it possible to move the vertical line dividing the 2 panels. So what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While opened Krusader you can try keyboard combinations for window manipulation:

- <kbd>Alt+F8</kbd> (for window resize);
- <kbd>Alt+F10</kbd> (to maximize/unmaximize its window).

Or move Krusader's configuration file with

```
mv ~/.kde/share/config/krusaderrc ~/krusaderrc_old
```

and then relaunch Krusader. It should reset to default settings.

Comment: 1.  Alt-F8 can only change window height. 2. Alt-F10 has no effect. 3. What happens to all my other settings if I move that file? 4. I presume Krusader had default settings when I installed it, so it wouldn't help anyway.

Comment: After moving this file Krusader will write new file with default settings. If you have changed some settings you can compare this files with `meld ~/.kde/share/config/krusaderrc ~/krusaderrc_old` and then revert them from GUI or as text.

Comment: The command "mv ~/.kde/share/config/krusaderrc ~/krusaderrc_old" gives this error-message: "mv: cannot stat '/home/henrik/.kde/share/config/krusaderrc': No such file or directory"
There is this file: "/home/henrik/.config/krusaderrc" but I am not sure how to change the command accordingly?

Comment: The command will change to `mv ~/.config/krusaderrc ~/krusaderrc_old`.

Comment: Pardon me for being a bit late here,  but wouldn't it be more logical to simply rename the file instead of moving it to some other folder?

Comment: We are trying to make Krusader recreate its default configuration file. Any action (of remove, rename, move) will help.

Comment: Finally I had time to check this. It solved the problem! It's just a bit sad that I originally spent a lot of time adjusting all the settings - now I can start all over again, or maybe try to compare the old and the new configuration file(?)

Comment: You can compare files with `meld` or `kdiff3`.